# How to add a has_many :through with polymorphic models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the models:

```
class User
  has_many :cars
  has_many :foods
end

class Car
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :colors, :as => :owner
end

class Food
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :colors, :as => :owner
end

class Color
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true   # This can be Food or Car
end
```

How can I say that `User` has many `Color` through both `Car` and `Food` on rails 3? And what about Rails 2?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should do it for ya (it should work in both Rails 2 and Rails 3):

```
class User
  has_many :colors
  has_many :cars, :through => :colors, :source => :owner, :source_type => "Car"
  has_many :foods, :through => :colors, :source => :owner, :source_type => "Food"
end

class Color
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

class Car
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :colors, :as => :owner
end

class Food
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :colors, :as => :owner
end
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but in my case `color_id` is not on the table `User`; instead, both table car and food have `user_id`. The Color have `owner_type` and `owner_id`, that are used only with `Car` and `Food`, not with `User`. So there is no direct connect between `User` and `Color`. I'm trying to reach all colors from the user, independently if it is a car color or a food color.

Comment: @fotanus may be you need to change the database structure as this makes more sense.

Comment: Upvoted, nice point, unfortunately change the database structure at this stage is not going to happen